# Removing and recreating file does not change its creation timestamp on NTFS

Tags: windows, file, timestamp, filesystems, qfile

I've experienced some strange problem with NTFS. The easiest way to reproduce it contains 3 steps.

1. Creating file foo.txt in arbitrary place, remembering its creation timestamp (it can be found in `properties` dialog for this file)
2. Removing it with `shift` + `delete`
3. Quickly recreating file with the same name, again looking at properties window. Creation timestamp didn't change since the first file creation (though `modified` timestamp is other).

This effect causes a great headake in implementing some complex logic in my Qt application. I am simply writing

```
QFile::remove(file);
```

but it is pretty clear that file removal must be some kind of flushed. What I want to know is an explanation of this effect and some tips how to aviod it. A way to correctly implement it in `Qt` (instead of simply writing) will be much appreciated. I have reproduced this effect on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Are you sure this is not exclusively an artifact of windows explorer perhaps caching some information?  Do you really have this problem from within Qt ?

Comment: @Mike Nakis, I first experienced this problem in c++ code, exploler is just a nice illustration.

Comment: workaround: rename the file to `"temp.temp"` and then `remove()` it.  (Though an answer explaining why this is happening would be interesting.)

Comment: @Mike Nakis, yep, thanks, I'm actually doing that dirty trick at the moment :) However that causes some other problem out of the scope of the question. So I'm also interested in clean aproach.

Comment: Strange, a batch file which deletes the file and re-creates it does not seem to suffer from this problem.

Comment: If I remember right, that behavior is by design. You can set file times explicitly yourself when you re-create the file.

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp, don't you remember where you read about it? Maybe post some prooflinks in answer and I will accept it.

Comment: As @Eugene says, Windows does this on purpose, as described in the accepted answer to the duplicate.  I'm not sure whether or not setting the times explicitly will prevent it from happening, but it sounds like a sensible thing to try.  Other options depend on your scenario.  In general, though, Windows applications are not expected to perform "complex logic" based on the creation timestamp.  (You might want to use the modification timestamp instead, for example.)

Comment: @Harry Johnston, wow, thanks a lot for the link and explanations! That fully answers my question!